# ViewState values doesn't get extracted from Request

Tags: regex, xpath, jmeter, viewstate

I have to do load testing for the Asp.net web application using jMeter.  But when I try to extract the ViewState values it doesn't work,IT will display Default value (Not Found). I tried in many ways,  How to work on Regular Expression Extractor? Please give me the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) guide, it contains example of correlation of __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION dynamic parameters using [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor).

Example configuration:

- Reference Name: variable of your choice
- CSS/JQuery Expression: `input[id=__VIEWSTATE]`
- Attribute: `value`

Answer (score 0):

ReferenceName: variable of your choice

RegularExpression: `__VIEWSTATE\|([^|]*)\|`

Template: `1$1`

Match No. (0 for random): 1